# Need deep link into Teams App into Approvals App and put my users right on their "received" approvals view

Tags: microsoft-teams

Need a deep link (or shareable link) to allow my users to go directly to the Approvals App (approvals hub) - received list in the Teams App (not web).

I've searched and searched and cannot find anything.  This is the closest I'm getting which gets me to a dialogue box that asks to open the approvals "hub" (app).

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/7c316234-ded0-4f95-8a83-8453d0876592?source=app-details-dialog

But, I'd like to "auto open" this and put them right on "their approvals" (received) page in the approvals app in the teams app.

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this deeplink: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/7c316234-ded0-4f95-8a83-8453d0876592/approvals

It's a [deeplink to the tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#deep-link-to-your-tab) of the Approvals app.